# Prove that there is a natural bijection between the set of $R[x]$-module structures on $M$ and $\mathrm{End}_{R-\mathsf{Mod}}(M)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

From *Algebra Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

> [image]

Suppose $\alpha: R \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(M)$ is an $R$-module structure on $M$. I would like to extend this to $R[x] \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(M)$ which would be an $R[x]$-module structure on $M$.

This really amounts to defining how the polynomial $x$ should act on an element $m \in M$, which I am not sure how to define.

How can this be done?

Comment: If $f \in End_R(M)$, then define the action of $g(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots +a_1x + a_0 \in F[x]$ on $v \in M$ by $g(x)v := a_nf^n(v) + a_{n-1}f^{n-1}(v) + \cdots + a_1f(v) + a_0$ where $f^k$ denotes the $k$-fold composition of $f$. Conversely, if $M$ is an $F[x]$-module define $f(v) := xv$ check to make sure $f$ is indeed an element of $End_R(M)$. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It may be helpful to remember why an $R$ module is an Abelian group $M$ with a homomorphism from $R \to End_{Ab}(M)$. Or, if $S$ is an $R$ algebra, then making an $R$ module $M$ into an $S$ algebra (extending the given $R$ module structure), is the same as an $R$-algebra homomorphism from $S$ to $End_{R}(M)$. A final thing that should be useful is the universal property of the ring $R[x]$. That is, if $S$ is any $R$-algebra, then the $R$-algebra maps from $R[x]$ to $S$ are freely determined by the choice of image for $x$.

Comment: @Mike I can see in the first sentence you take $f \in \mathrm{End}_{R-\mathsf{Mod}}(M)$ to a ring homomorphism from $R[x] \to \mathrm{End}_{\mathsf{Ab}}(M)$. However, in your second, what is $x$ in the definition of $f$?

Comment: @Al Jebr First, I should have a $v$ next to the $a_0$, sorry about that! In regards to your question, we know that $M$ is an $F[x]$-module. Hence, the polynomial $g(x) = x$ acts on $M$ in some way. We are simply defining the function $f$ by the action of this polynomial $x$.

Comment: @Mike If $M$ is an $R$-module, then the ring evaluation homomorphism $R[x] \to R$ where $f(x) \mapsto f(r)$ determines a $R[x]$-module structure on $M$. Now can't we define an action of $R[x]$ on $M$ as $(a_0+a_1x +\cdots + a_n x^n)\cdot m = (a_0+a_1r+ \cdots + a_n r^n)\cdot f(m)$?

Comment: @AlJebr Yes, this does appear to be an action. However, the way you are phrasing this action 
 still has the form that I claim in my first answer. It arrises from $f \in End_R(M)$ defined as $f(m) = rm$ (for the choice of $r$ that you choose in your evaluation homomorphism). Check my formula in the first answer if you do not believe me.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking where multiplication by $x$ sends a general element $m \in M$, but have no place to send it. What if I gave you a map $f : M \to M$? Any guesses on where it should go?